# Walking uphill, downhill and on a plane

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A person walks downhill at 10 km/h, uphill at 6 km/h and on the plane at 7.5 km/h. If the person takes 3 hours to go from a place A to another place B, and 1 hour on the way back, the distance between A and B is
>   $\begin{array}1 1. 15 km && 2. 23.5 km \\ 3. 16 km && 4. \text{Given data is insufficient to calculate the distance}\end{array}$

Attempt: If he walked $X km$ downhill, $Y km$ uphill, and $Zkm$ on a plane, we get
\begin{equation}
{Xkm\over 10 km/h}+{Ykm\over 6 km/h}+{Zkm\over 7.5 km/h}=3\to (1) 
\end{equation} and 
\begin{equation}
{Xkm\over 6 km/h}+{Ykm\over 10 km/h}+{Zkm\over 7.5 km/h}=1\to (2) 
\end{equation}

We are supposed to find distance between A and B, that is, $X+Y+Z$. Adding those equations and simplifying, we get $2(X+Y)+Z=30$ and I am stuck.

I also tried:

1. $2(X+Y)+Z=(X+Y)+(X+Y+Z)$ and substituting each option for $X+Y+Z$, and try solve for $X,Y,Z$, and only option 1 fits the above equations (and for 2,3 it gives negative value for $X$ and/or $Y$.)
2. Guessing $Z=0$, it suggests option 1 again.

But both are not the "right" way to solve it.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x/6 + y/10 + z/7.5 = 3 \implies 5x + 3y + 4z  = 90$

$x/10 + y/6 + z/7.5 = 1 \implies 3x + 5y + 4z = 30$

$8x + 8y + 8z = 120$

$x + y + z = 15$

No. 1.

Comment: and 2x - 2y =  60 = 4(x + y + z).  I think we should put negative distances into industrial use as I'm sure they can be quite useful.

Answer (score 2):

The question has no answer, and in fact, the situation described is impossible. Proof:

If you subtract your first equation from the second one, you get
$$\frac{x}{10}-\frac{x}{6} + \frac{y}{6} - \frac{y}{10} = 2$$

which simplifies to $y-x = 30$

Now, knowing that both $x$ and $y$ are both positive numbers, you know that $y=30+x>30+0=30$. However, since $y>30$ and $z>0$, you now know that $$1=\frac{x}6 + \frac y{10} + \frac{z}{7.5} > \frac06+\frac{30}{10} + \frac0{7.5} = 3,$$

which means that $1>3$ which is impossible.

Comment: That's how they do it in Russia.  In America we have time traveling negative distance shoes.

Comment: @fleablood Yeah. Don't get me wrong, your answer is correct and gets the point across well, however I just wanted to point out how stupid the question actually is.

Comment: [Interesting](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1619225/45937)! Even I feared that when I saw $y-x=30$, but $15$ fitting into the scenario made me rule out thoughts in those lines!

Comment: @JessePFrancis I am not saying that the answer by fleablood is wrong. In fact, I would bet that his answer is precisely what the person making the question had in mind. However, when asking such  "real life" questions, you have to take into account limitations like "distance cannot be negative", and if you don't, your question becomes nonsensical.

Comment: @5xum, true! This was asked in aptitude section of an exam, and fleablood's answer just fits in, fact that one's given just few seconds to spend on this question. But that doesn't make the question not wrong! Will surely raise a report to the [council](http://csirhrdg.res.in/)!

Comment: I saw that y - x = 30 which I thought was odd but I plugged through anyway, for reasons that in the light of day aren't so clear.  You can't solve for any x, y, and z individually as you have only two equations and three unknowns by we can solve.  y = x + 30 and x + y + z = 15.  And clearly at least one of x, y, z are negative.

Comment: In a post I'm too lazy to look up, there was an anecdote about students being asked to find the area of a right triangle with hypotenuse 10 and altitude from hypotenuse to right angle vertex of 6.  Americans, supposedly, plugged in the formula and got 30, whereas Russian students noted that such a triangle is impossible.  Hence my joke about Russia.  The anecdote actually kind of pissed me off for reasons I won't get into now.

Comment: @fleablood, I remember reading that, in some comments here in math.SE! Anyway, thank you, both of you! Specially 5xum, this answer is a new learning!